# Wordpress Contact Form 7 plugin issue in IE8

Tags: php, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

I have used contact form 7 plugin woth wordpress 3.3.1,
While validating the form the spinning arrow is shown but nothing happens in ie8, but for other browsers it is working perfectly.
I have tried disabling other plugins, & switching the theme but no help.
disabling javascript will do the work but i want the form to be submitted by ajax.

Please help !

Comment: This is most probably due to a conflict between plugins. Try deactivating all other plugins.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-ie8-and-7-not-submitting This URL is having some solutions. Check and fix it.

Comment: Contact Form 7 FAQs http://contactform7.com/faq/#My_contact_form_behaves_oddly_on_certain_browsers

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.the solution will be:

```
1. remove the Anchor
2. Add a "?" before "#"
3. Link the invalid address (in this case "/%23wpcf7-f1-p233-ol") to correct one using Apache ReWriteEngine
4. Fix the stupid IE !! ;-)
```

Good Luck